# Bug in LogLinearPlot? Mathematica v11.0

Tags: plotting, bugs, logarithmic-scale

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

I'm trying to plot a sequence of functions. I wrote the code in two seemingly equivalent ways, but it produces different results. First method:

```
FX = Table[(x - 1 + d)/(1 + x), {d, 0, 1, 0.2}]
LogLinearPlot[FX, {x, 1, 1000}, PlotRange -> {{1, 1000}, {0, 1}}]
```

Here is the result:

[image: First method]

This didn't look right, so I repeated the same thing a second time, except this time I substituted the list directly into the plotting command:

```
LogLinearPlot[{(-1. + x)/(1 + x), (-0.8 + x)/(1 + x), (-0.6 + x)/(
  1 + x), (-0.4 + x)/(1 + x), (-0.2 + x)/(1 + x), (0. + x)/(
  1 + x)}, {x, 1, 1000}, PlotRange -> {{1, 1000}, {0, 1}}]
```

Here is the result...

[image: Second method]

Clearly the plots are different (the second one is correct). If I do an ordinary Plot command the plots are identical. Any idea what's going on? I'm using Mathematica 11.0. I did a bit of testing, and it appears that if I use the command:

```
Plot[FX, {x, 0, Log[1000]}, PlotRange -> {{0, Log[1000]}, {0, 1}}]
```

I can reproduce the same curves as in the first plot. So apparently it's actually using linear scales for the LogLinearPlot command when I pass it a list...

Comment: 11.0.0 or 11.0.1? In 11.0.1 I get identical graphs for both (well the coloring differs, but small matter). Consider upgrading?

Comment: definitely a bug. Fixed in 11.0.1. The coloring issue is fixed in a future release.

Comment: Aha! Thanks --- I'll upgrade.

Comment: For proper coloring, use `Evaluate`: `LogLinearPlot[Evaluate@FX, {x, 1, 1000}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]`